# Why is the sigmoid curve called sigmoid?

Tags: math-history

What is the history behind the naming?  The Greek letter sigma does not have an S-shape, but the Latin letter s obviously does.

Which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Hi! There is another site in SE network about History of Mathematics! https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ maybe you'll find a more satisfactory answer, posting your question there. :-)

Comment: Sigma is written $\varsigma$ at the end of a word.

Answer (score 3):

Also in ancient Greece, sigma was written as "C".